# Question about alias declarations in template class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am confusing about alias declarations in template situation.
Example:(Just toy for "demo")

```
template<class T>
class A {
private:
    using t = T;

public:
    t add(T a, T b);
};

// alias declarations
template<class T>
using tt = typename A<T>::t;

template<class T>
typename A<T>::t A<T>::add(T a, T b){
    return a+b;
}

// error !!!!
template<class T>
tt<T> A<T>::add(T a, T b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Error information:

> g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -pedantic-errors main.cpp && ./a.out ; echo Program returned $?
>   main.cpp:23:7: error: no declaration matches 'tt A::add(T, T)'
>    tt A::add(T a, T b) {
>          ^~~~
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
>   Program returned 1

Is any method to write in alias simplify form ?

Comment: Please include the full error in your question.

Comment: Works fine [over here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a9b992330f4cdd1).

Comment: @Quentin c++14 != c++2a ;)

Comment: @YSC *grumble grumble cookies grumble*. Still works in C++14 (and 11 while we're at it).

Comment: @Quentin [g++ rejects it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b618a950567051)

Comment: @YSC interesting. It still fails with the latest version on Wandbox as well.

Comment: I've seen that bug before. There is a bug report somewhere.

Comment: Is it the same: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1608724? It's a red hat portal though.

Comment: Or this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69481?

Comment: I guess this is a variation of [CWG 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2).

Comment: I'm sort of supprised [clang accepts this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45f11a1f0e07dd39), but if you add `()` around the `sizeof(T)<10` clause it rejects it.